# PhpStorm Ideolog regexp

Tags: regex, phpstorm

In my project I'm using own format of log, as following

```
[2020-11-17 10:46:27][INFO][RCSE\Core\Database\Database] Database connected successfully.
```

But I wasn't been able to tune Ideolog's regexp for this format correctly. I've built expression using [regexr](http://regexr.com/5go8a) like this:

```
^\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]\[[A-Z]*\]\[[A-Z\\]*\] .*/i
```

Full setting in screenshot:

[image: PhpStorm Ideolog settings]

Could use some help with setting this up properly.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Barmar and @LazyOne, it was solved!
Current regex looks like

`(?i)^\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\]\[([A-Z]*)\]\[([A-Z\\]*)\] .*$`

And settings entry looks like

[image: Final setting]

Comment: Can you include your actual PHP code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen They're not writing code, ideolog is a plugin in the PhpStorm IDE for displaying log files. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9746-ideolog

Comment: #1 From what I see from 1) your RegEx and 2) your Ideolog screenshot ... your RegEx does not have any capturing groups that Ideolog needs to tell what is what -- your RegEx just verifies/matches whole line and that's it. try this one instead: `^\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\]\[([A-Z]*)\]\[([A-Z\\]*)\] .*` (copied from that RegExr website after modifying it -- https://regexr.com/5goa6)

Comment: #2 Make sure you select the right capturing groups in Ideolog: I believe Time should be 1, Severity = 2, Category =3. #3 As Barmar said -- you may need to make your RegEx that Java can use. If you cannot, you may use `A-Za-z` instead of just `A-Z` to specify case insensitivity.

Comment: @LazyOne i did as you and @Barmar suggested - now it highlight outputs, but still tells about log format not being recognized, current regex is `(?:i)^\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\]\[([A-Z]*)\]\[([A-Z\\]*)\] .*$`
UPD: i noticed what : weren't suposed to be there, after removing it it works fine now! Thanks! Could you make these comments as answer so i could mark them correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideolog uses Java regular expressions, you can't append `/i` to the end to make it case-insensitive. You can put `(?i)` at the beginning to turn on the case-insensitive flag for the regexp.

```
(?i)^\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]\[[A-Z]*\]\[[A-Z\\]*\] .*$
```

Also, are you sure that the field after `[INFO]` only contains letters and backslash, but not numbers or underscore? You might be better off using `\w` to match any alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Yes, it just contains namespace of class which log's something, i wrote logger myself.